# RegExp Parser for Tag-Like String

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

In an application I'm writing, at some point, I want to be able to parse a tag-like string with RegExp so that it is modified, such as:

```
"{b}This is BOLD{/b}".replace(/\{b\}(.*?)\{\/b\}/gi, "00b3f[ $1 00b3d]");

// Returns "00b3f[ This is BOLD 00b3d]"
```

I am able to do this easily, but it gets complicated when a more complex string is passed to the function, for example:

```
"{red} This is RED {red} This also should be red {/red} and this {/red}"
.replace(/\{red\}(.*?)\{\/red\}/gi, "00b4f[ $1 00b4d]");

// Returns:
// "00b4f[  This is RED {red} This also should be red  00b4d] and this {/red}"

// Where the output should be:
// "00b4f[  This is RED 00b4f[ This also should be red 00b4d] and this 00b4d]"
```

I would like to solve this problem with a simple RegExp but I can't find a way to do it! I think I could do this with a while-loop but it would get too messy. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't solve this problem with a regexp because the language you are describing is context-sensitive but not regular - in simple terms it means "you need memory to parse it" which is what you've observed. I recommend a simple recursive descent parser.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1026459

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex can't deal with nested expressions (unless you have access to a powerful implementation of regex, which javascript doesn't), so a pure-regex solution is out of the question. But there's still an easy way to do this:

1. replace all occurences of `\{(\w+)\}((?:(?!\{\w+\}).)*)\{\/\1\}` (this matches a `{tag}...{/tag}` pair, but only if it does not contain another `{tag}` ) with `00b4f[ $2 00b4d]` .
2. repeat until there are no more matches.

---

To make this dynamic, use a callback function for the replacement:

```
var tagPattern = /\{(\w+)\}((?:(?!\{\w+\}).)*)\{\/\1\}/g,
    tagReplacer = function ($0, $1, $2) {
        switch ($1) {
            case "b": return "00b3f[" + $2 + " 00b3d]";
            case "red": return "00b4f[" + $2 + " 00b4d]";
            default: return $2;
        }
    };

while (tagPattern.test(sourceString)) {
    sourceString = sourceString.replace(tagPattern, tagReplacer);
}
```

Comment: Very nice solution. You could extend that by mentioning replace callbacks, I'm pretty sure the OP will need them.

Comment: + 1 Very very cool. A small while loop and a callback will make this very dynamic and easy to implement!

Comment: @Tomalak: I've never really used JavaScript, so chances are OP knows more about replace callbacks than I do.

Comment: @Rawing I took the liberty to add that.

Comment: @Tomalak: In that case, I will take the liberty to upvote your comment, at the very least. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. That's what this whole "everything can be edited" thing is for, after all.